# interactive R startup script

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to run interactive R (Windows XP) with an input script that runs a few commands, and then leaves me at the R command line prompt. However, when I run it, it exits.

For example, here's the input file:

```
test.r: 
x = 1
x
```

Here's what happens when I run it with the input file as a parameter:

```
C:\>R --file test.t
>x = 1 
>x
[1] 1
C:\>  <--- exits and returns to prompt
```

Is there any way to run this without R exiting?

Comment: I added an [r] tag as that seemed relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it the other way around.

Just write a script that starts the *normal* R GUI or terminal application (per your choice), but then also place a file `.Rprofile` in the same directory which contains the code you want executed each and every time.

See `help(Startup)` on details about the files R looks up at startup and this may become clearer.

Comment: Thank you - it worked perfectly. I've made the script a bit more complex and am running into another issue, which I'll post as a separate question.

Comment: Glad to have been of help. Also note that R does differentiate between interactive and non-interactive mode for certain things.